# I need to extract duplicate information from the same table however it not the entire information in the row that is the same

Tags: sql, sql-server

I picked up that the system is creating duplicate billing on a policy level when user apply a cancellation on a accidental claim.

I need to extract all the duplicated billing transactions from the transactions table however the entire row is not duplicate just a few fields as the billing increases the balance and also creates a new GID and new contract movement.

The billing movementid is 101
TransactionType id is 100

Matching information will be ContractGid, AccountingPeriodID, Amount
Fields that will be different Billinggid, Balance.

I was hoping i could just write a where statement for example

```
select *
from LIF_TMS_T_FinancialTransaction
where ContractGID = 'DF31A6BD-FC48-4722-A820-A66500C1E136'
and accountingperiodid = accountingperiodid
```

or any of the other matches and then the extract should only pull

```
select *
from LIF_TMS_T_FinancialTransaction
where ContractGID = 'DF31A6BD-FC48-4722-A820-A66500C1E136'
and accountingperiodid = accountingperiodid


GID ContractGID ContractMovementCount   MovementDate    ContractMovementID  AccountingPeriodID  Amount  Balance
31E7720D-FE34-47AD-92B3-AA0300B13FA5    DF31A6BD-FC48-4722-A820-A66500C1E136    2   2019-03-01 00:00:00.000 101 201649  -61 -61
AB46BC52-9CD3-4C9D-BEB2-AA1500F5A830    DF31A6BD-FC48-4722-A820-A66500C1E136    5   2019-03-01 00:00:00.000 101 201649  -61 -122
AE4C06E1-B1E8-41EE-88A3-AA070113C8B1    DF31A6BD-FC48-4722-A820-A66500C1E136    2   2019-03-02 00:00:00.000 810 201649  61  -61
```

Based on the above table i would only want the first two records to be extract.
This is just a sample

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't post your table definition, I can only offer general guidance.  if you know the columns that are duplicated, something like this will do it

```
with t as (
    select *, rc = rowcount() over(partition by <duplicate columns>)
)
from mytable

select * from t where rc > 1 -- to show duplicate rows
delete * from t where rc > 1 -- to delete duplicate rows
```